# javascript function to change visibility of elements by sending the integer of the next element

Tags: javascript

I have a page with elements such as

```
<div id="div1" style="display: block;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div4" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div5" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div6" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="div7" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
```

I need a javascript function that will change the visible element by plus or minus one. Only one should be visible.

This works well with the selected answer. I had a headache with a localStorage value until I realized I needed to parse the string. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses no jQuery just because there is no jQuery-tag in topic. (Edit, misunderstood)

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="plus">+</a><a href="" id="minus">-</a>
<div class="plusable" style="display: block;">Stuff1</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff2</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff3</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff4</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff5</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff6</div>
<div class="plusable" style="display: none;">Stuff7</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var plusButton = document.getElementById('plus');
    var minusButton = document.getElementById('minus');
    var plusables = document.getElementsByClassName('plusable');
    var current = 0;

    function hideCurrent () {
        plusables[current].style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showCurrent () {
        plusables[current].style.display = 'block';
    }

    plusButton.onclick = function () {
        if (current === plusables.length - 1) {
            return false;
        }

        hideCurrent();
        current += 1;
        showCurrent();
        return false;
    };

    minusButton.onclick = function () {
        if (current === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        hideCurrent();
        current -= 1;
        showCurrent();
        return false;
    };
};
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYk39/1/)

Comment: ...because there is no jQuery-tag in topic
agreed: 35-liner is better than 1-liner

Comment: When you don't want to or can load jQuery, it sure is.

Comment: This works well, though can we enhance it as I note in the addition to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("div:visible").hide().next().show();
```

or

```
$("div:visible").hide().previous().show();
```

Comment: The div elements that need to have visibility changed are within another div. Using this hides the outer div and all the elements within. How could this be tweaked to function on the child div elements?

Comment: $("div:visible").children().hide()...

Answer (score 0):

Try that but not tested, it uses JQuery

```
function changeVisible(var divID, var operation)
{
   //Get the new div id
   var n=divID.split("div");
   if (operation == "+")
      var divNumber = parseInt('n[1]',10) + 1;
  else if (operation == "-")
      var divNumber = parseInt('n[1]',10) - 1;
   var newDIV = "div"+divNumber;

   //Using JQuery
   $("#"+newDIV).css("display","block");
   $("#"+divID).css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`displayed` is the number of the div currently displayed, starting from 0 (so `div1` has the number 0, `div2` is 1 ...)

`howmany` means how many divs you have in the cycle

```
var displayed = 0;
var howmany = 7;
function mod(a,b){
    return ((a%b)+b)%b;
}
function f(amount){
     var div = document.querySelector("#div"+(displayed + 1));
     div.style.display = "none";
     displayed = mod(displayed + amount , howmany);
     var div = document.querySelector("#div"+(displayed + 1));
     div.style.display = "block";

}
document.
 querySelector("#addOne").
 addEventListener("click", function () {f(1)});
document.
 querySelector("#subOne").
 addEventListener("click", function () {f(-1)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uSkq4/2/